# Apply a binary operator to each element in an array

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, array-algorithms

Given a binary functor (or functor-like) object which takes two arrays of type `T*` and a size and returns `T*`, what is a canonical way to apply this functor to each object in an array, returning a new one?

I.e., something equivalent to, but shorter and less error prone than the following:

```
template<typename T, typename O>
T* apply(const T* a1, const T* a2, size_t size, O op) {
  T* out = new[size];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    out[i] = op(a1[i], a2[i]);
  }
  return out;
}
```

I am not too fussed about the details of how the output is allocated. In the above example it is allocated on the heap, but maybe other variants overwrite one of the inputs or write into a provided buffer, or maybe it's using `std::array<>` and returns that, etc.

Comment: Pretty sure the pattern in the stl would be to use output iterators (e.g., `std::back_inserter`).

Comment: @StephenNewell - sure but how about the "iterate over pairs of elements from two separate ranges" part? That's the part I am stuck on.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code as `op(a1[i], a1[i])`.  Why not just take two iterators and use `std::advance` on each?  Whether you want to make the caller ensure both ranges are the same size is up to you (looks like `std::equal` has forms that take both three and four iterators).

Comment: I suppose you can use the version of `std::transform()` that receive two input iterator and a binary operator (version 3 or 4 in [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform))

Comment: @max66 - thanks, it was the answer I was looking for. Somehow I remained unaware of those forms...

Answer (score 2):

You are mentioning working with arrays, but with a function which takes iterators/pointers, where we've lost the type information from the array(s), similar to array to pointer decay in C-style treatment of C-style array arguments.

If applicable (given restraints from the call site), you could instead make use of `std::array` to avoid the loss of size information, while still writing a size-agnostic function template with the constraint that both array arguments should be of the same size (which we could expect as you are performing a typical zip and map operation).

E.g. using [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) to apply the binary operator to pair-wise elements in the to array arguments:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename BinaryOperator, std::size_t N>
auto apply(const std::array<T, N>& arr1, const std::array<T, N>& arr2,
           const BinaryOperator& op) {
  std::array<T, N> result{};
  std::transform(arr1.begin(), arr1.end(), arr2.begin(), result.begin(), op);
  return result;
}

int main() {
  const std::array<int, 5> arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  const std::array<int, 5> arr2 = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
  const auto results = apply(arr1, arr2, [](int i, int j) { return i + j; });
  for (const auto num : results) {
    std::cout << num << " ";
  }  // 7 9 11 13 15
}
```

Or, if you may use C++14, [`std::integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) combined with parameter pack expansion:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

namespace detail {
template <typename Array, typename BinaryOperator, std::size_t... I>
Array apply_impl(const Array& arr1, const Array& arr2, const BinaryOperator& op,
                 std::index_sequence<I...>) {
  return {op(arr1[I], arr2[I])...};
}
}

template <typename T, typename BinaryOperator, std::size_t N,
          typename Indices = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
auto apply(const std::array<T, N>& arr1, const std::array<T, N>& arr2,
           const BinaryOperator& op) {
  return detail::apply_impl(arr1, arr2, op, Indices{});
}

int main() {
  const std::array<int, 5> arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  const std::array<int, 5> arr2 = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
  const auto results = apply(arr1, arr2, [](int i, int j) { return i + j; });
  for (const auto num : results) {
    std::cout << num << " ";
  }  // 7 9 11 13 15
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Yes, I use the term "arrays" loosely here to mean something which has an array type in memory, but is passed as a pointer/size pair, not necessarily something that has compile-time array type within the function. Such is the usual case of dealing with arrays in C++.

In general I expect my objects to have dynamic size not known at compile time, so maybe `vector<>` is a better container analog for what I am doing that `std::array`.